PySide6.QMediaPlayer Cannot play audio on Windows 11
I tried to develop an audio player app using PySide6, but I found that I couldn't play any audio,The program is running normally, but no sound is playing. The mediaStatusChanged signal of QMediaPlayer is not being triggered either. The QMediaPlayer's status always remained MediaStatus.NoMedia, regardless of whether it was an MP3 or WAV file. The program didn't report any errors.
Here is my code:
import os
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.setupUi(self)

        self.playButton = QPushButton('Play')

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.audioOutput = QAudioOutput()

        self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audioOutput)
        self.player.errorOccurred.connect(self.error)
        self.player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.status_changed)

        self.playButton.pressed.connect(self.play)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.playButton)

    def play(self):
        file_path = './resources/audio/City.wav'
        absolute_path = os.path.abspath(file_path)
        print(f'absolute_path: {absolute_path}')

        self.player.setSource(QUrl(absolute_path))
        self.player.play()

        print(f'Volume: {self.audioOutput.volume()}')
        print(f'Devices: {self.audioOutput.device()}')
        print(f"player status: {self.player.mediaStatus()}")

    def error(self, error):
        print(f'Error: {error}')

    def status_changed(self, status):
        print(f'Status changed: {status}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

the console output:
absolute_path: D:\pythonProject\winapp\resources\audio\City.wav
Volume: 1.0
Devices: <PySide6.QtMultimedia.QAudioDevice object at 0x0000025E0EC86E00>
player status: MediaStatus.NoMedia

I confirm that the paths to these WAV and MP3 files are correct and can play normally in Windows Media Player.
I use
PySide6 6.7.3,
Windows 11 22631.4169

It should be possible to play a wav file on Windows without needing to install any extra codecs. If it was just something wrong with the audio source, there would be different status and/or error output. It looks like the media backend isn't loading properly. Try adding os.environ['QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS'] = '1' to the top of the script and look for the media plugin in the output. And as a further sanity check, add these lines to the end of __init__: print(f'error: {self.player.errorString()!r}'); print(f'codecs: {QMediaFormat().supportedAudioCodecs(QMediaFormat.ConversionMode.Decode)!r}').

You need to use QUrl.fromLocalFile() as also shown in the example of the QMediaPlayer documentation. You should also be very careful in using relative paths, as they are always based on the cwd, not the path of the script.

@musicamante If the url scheme is empty or "file", QMediaPlayer will do this: url = QUrl.fromUserInput(url.toString(), QDir.currentPath(), QUrl.UserInputResolutionOption.AssumeLocalFile). This means it makes no difference whether the original source url is relative or not. And as I pointed out in my previous comment, if the problem was merely a wrong file-path, the behaviour would be totally different, because the player would at least attempt to load the media, and then fail with appropriate status/error output. The NoMedia status indicates a more fundamental problem.

@musicamante PS: I originally wondered whether an unresolved url might cause an issue, but when I tested on Linux (with all forms of url), I could not reproduce the output. Anyway, I'd be quite surprised if the behaviour was radically different on Windows.

@ekhumoro Uh, I thought that NoMedia was also used when no file was found too. About the relative path, I believe that my suggestion remains if the OP assumes that the path of the media file is relative to the python file, even considering fromUserInput(), as QDir.currentPath() is based on the cwd, isn't it? Anyway, at this point, I wouldn't be surprised to find out that this is yet another 6.7 bug...

@musicamante Yes, by "no difference" I just meant setSource can handle relative files transparently. But in any case, I think this may be the least of the OPs problems. With an invalid file-path, the OP should see something like LoadingMedia ... ResourceError ... InvalidMedia. Otherwise, a bug or system setup issue seems quite likely.

@ekhumoro
Thanks for your reply.
Here is output:
error: 'Not available' codecs: []
@musicamante
Thanks for your reply.I try to use  QUrl.fromLocalFile() but its not work too.

@Lemon The fact that codecs shows an empty list is a quite relevant aspect (at that point, the file path doesn't matter, as no codecs seem available to begin with): it clearly means that there's something wrong with your setup, either based on your configuration, the specific Qt version, or a combination of both (as said above, the 6.7.* branch is known to be quite bugged, and the switch to ffmpeg introduced many unwanted/unexpected issues).

@Lemon Please add this line to the top of the test script: os.environ['QT_LOGGING_RULES'] = 'qt.multimedia.*=true'. Then run the script and show all the output in your question. You should also try adding: os.environ['QT_MEDIA_BACKEND'] = 'windows'. If that makes no difference, also try: os.environ['QT_MEDIA_BACKEND'] = 'ffmpeg'. If neither works, that suggests the current PySide6 Windows wheels are totally broken, so you should try downgrading to PySide-6.7.2 (or perhaps even PySide-6.6.3.1).

@ekhumoro I added os.environ['QT_MEDIA_BACKEND'] = 'windows', and the music could be played normally afterwards! But strangely, adding os.environ['QT_LOGGING_RULES'] = 'qt.multimedia.*=true' did not result in any additional QT log output in the console. And I found that if I changed os.environ['QT_MEDIA_BACKEND'] from 'windows' to 'ffmpeg', everything would go back to normal.Thank you very much for you help me to solve this thorny problem.
